# What does "The by-gone-day proclaym'd" mean in scene ii, act I of The Winter's Tale?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, verbs, early-modern-english, shakespeare

In the [second scene](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Shakespeare_-_First_Folio_facsimile_(1910)/The_Winters_Tale/Act_1_Scene_2) of *The Winter's Tale*, Hermione says:

> I had thought (Sir) to haue held my peace, vntill
> You had drawne Oathes from him, not to stay: you (Sir)
> Charge him too coldly. Tell him, you are sure
> All in Bohemia's well: this satisfaction,
> **The by-gone-day proclaym'd**, say this to him,
> He's beat from his best ward.

I tried [to decode](https://www.shakespeareswords.com/Public/Play.aspx?Content=Text&WorkId=35&Act=1&Scene=2) this sentence but to no avail. I looked up
*proclaim* [in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proclaim), but methinks the verb does not mean *declare* here.
What does *The by-gone-day proclaym'd* mean in Hermione's speech?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Proclaym’d* here means *revealed* or *demonstrated*. To paraphrase:

> *Tell him you are sure all’s well in Bohemia — as demonstrated by the bygone day.*

> **proclaim**, *v.*
> **I. 4. a.** *transitive*. *figurative*. Of a thing: to make known or manifest; to be evidence or an indication of, demonstrate; to reveal
> *as*; to show or prove to *be*.
>   <sub>[selected usage examples]</sub>
>  <sub>1603    W. SHAKESPEARE *Hamlet* i.
> iii. 72     The apparell oft proclaimes the man.</sub>
> <sub>c1704     M. PRIOR *Henry & Emma* 242     His
> steps proclaim no lover's haste.</sub> 
>  <sub>1757     T.
> GRAY *Ode II* iii. ii, in *Odes* 19     Her eye proclaims
> her of the Briton-Line.</sub> 
>  <sub>1813     W. SCOTT
> *Rokeby* i. 11     Then did his silence long proclaim A struggle between fear and shame.</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

'[Proclaim](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/proclaim)' is used here in the sense of

> to announce or declare in an official or formal manner

---

On [Litcharts](https://www.litcharts.com/shakescleare/shakespeare-translations/the-winters-tale/act-1-scene-2), "*this satisfaction the by-gone-day proclaym'd*" is transcribed as

> we heard good news yesterday

"*This satisfaction*" refers to the certainty that all in Bohemia is well, and apparently it was yesterday ('[bygone](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bygone)' day as 'former' day), that this news was brought to Hermione's attention—or, at least, she wants Leontes to use this to entreat Polixenes to stay.